# Sqlite FTS: Performing AND across two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I need to perform a query which matches two different terms across different columns. For example:

```
select * from messages where messagefts match "categories:Office AND subject:Hi there";
```

From my perspective this should work as I have records which should have an Office category with that specific subject. The query works using OR instead of AND, but when I try and use AND I get no results.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Are you sure you have records which should match this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an implied `AND`:

```
select * from messages
where messagefts
match "categories:Office subject:Hi there";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I'm a bit confused as to why the explicit AND didn't work though.

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of the language specification.